# Microsoft Access Token Request Error - 400 Bad Request

Tags: rest, api, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get access token from access code. but there is a error of 400 Bad Request error

I am using this link to get Access code

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost/Home/About&scope=mail.read

in response of this link i am getting the code in query string with return url
code=Mh12d04c8-8ea9-c82b-8cc5-b93cf913382c

i am using this code to get access token

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token?redirect_uri=http://localhost:51296/Home/AAA&client_id=xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&client_secret=Rmi2PNLPNM5agLh5aT5G82W&code=Mh12d04c8-8ea9-c82b-8cc5-b93cf913382c&scope=mail.read

But it is giving 400 Bad Request. please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: It will normally return an extended error code and error message. Can you check if that is the case and add them? 

For example, when I click the login.microsoftonline.com link, the error page has them in the lower right corner: "AADSTS90056: This endpoint only accepts POST requests. Received a GET request". 

Your POST would get a different error code.

Comment: Also your redirect uri doesn't match between the calls. It needs to match what you've set during app registration

Comment: @RasmusW no i did not get any error like this "AADSTS90056". i got the the bad request error 400. please help me.

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT my both return uri match which i set during registration

Comment: my another question is that "May i use personal Microsoft account with Microsoft Graph API?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this kind of issue , as @RasmusW suggested , you could use a tool like Fiddler to find the inner error message in the response . And as @ Dan Kershaw pointed out , you need to make sure reply address url in token request should match the reply address in Authorization code request . Otherwise you will get the error : The reply address 'xxxxx' does not match the reply address 'xxxx' provided when requesting Authorization code.

According to your request , you are using the Authorization Code Flow with v2.0 endpoint . You must add a “**grant_type**” parameter in the token request , and the value must be “**authorization_code**”  for the authorization code flow. Please check it first if the inner error message is “AADSTS90014: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type” . Please click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code) for more details about OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow in v2.0 endpoint.

> May i use personal Microsoft account with Microsoft Graph API

Yes .The v2.0 endpoint allow developers to write apps that accept sign-in from both Microsoft Accounts and Azure AD accounts, using a single auth endpoint.

Comment: Thank you @Nan Yu - MSFT. and please help me that how to trace error in Fiddler?

Comment: can you please provide me the code sample for this?

Comment: For how to use Fiddler to debug , you could get a lot of tutorials on the internet , for example , this one :http://www.asjava.com/tools/fiddler-tutorial-how-to-use-fiddler/ . For how to use Microsoft Graph API , you could click https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/auth_overview for code samples .

Comment: Thank you @Nan Yu - MSFT. it is working for me but as you given me the Microsoft Graph API link. i got the response as Unauthorized. and in Fiddler i got the response as "code=unauthenticated" and "message=Must be authenticated to use '/drive' syntax" when i use my Microsoft Account. Please help me for this.

Comment: @Dhruti Rathod , Have you got the access token successfully , which api call  you are using when you get the error ? You could check the microsoft graph api document ,check whether your access token has permissions to make your api call .

Comment: yes i got the token successfully. and i am using "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive" api call with Authorization "Authorization: Bearer <access token>". and i have given all permission as it is my personal Microsoft account.

Comment: is it possible to access personal Microsoft account drive(not a Business account) items from "graph.microsoft.com" api?

Comment: @Dhruti Rathod . Yes , you could use Microsoft Graph to access personal OneDrive with Active Directory OAuth v2 endpoints .You could check the detail steps from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code/ , You could use "https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FFiles.read" scope for testing .

Comment: @Dhruti Rathod Please mark this reply , so anyone else could refer to when they meet same error as yours.

Comment: please see my this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42408512/microsoft-graph-api-resource-not-found-when-access-workbook-of-onedrive . i think you can surely help me. please help me.  @Nan Yu - MSFT