# Microsoft Graph API Resource not found when access workbook of onedrive

Tags: excel, api, office365, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I'm building a application that connects to OneDrive for personal Microsoft account via the Graph API.My goal is to make a application from that i can access ondrive workbook content.

For reference document i am using this document : https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/excel

here i have 2 questions:

**Que 1:**

https://graph.microsoft.com/{version}/me/drive/items/{id}/workbook/

for this link i am using v1.0 for {version} 
and for {id} i am using "7FA7C48C26BC284B!114" this. it is Excel workbook id.

**is it correct?**

**Que 2:**

i see in the example from the same page /{version}/me/drive/items/01CYZLFJGUJ7JHBSZDFZFL25KSZGQTVAUN/workbook/

this long id: "01CYZLFJGUJ7JHBSZDFZFL25KSZGQTVAUN"

but i did not get this much long id from any response. **is it the issue for recourse not fount error?**

please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel REST API is currently not available for consumer/personal accounts. We are working on enabling this in the near future. In the meantime it is available for files in OneDrive for Business and SharePoint.

Comment: https://graph.microsoft.com/{version}/me/drive/items/{id}/workbook/ . Does this api work with personal account?

Comment: That is what I meant by the Excel REST API, it is enabled for commercial accounts only, at this point in time

Comment: @Yina-MSFT It appears Excel REST API is still not enabled for personal accounts.  Any updates on when it may be?

Comment: A better error message then what I receive, "Workbook Not Found" would be "Feature Not Available".  The workbook *is* there.

Comment: Microsoft could at least make it clear in the documentation that the feature is only available for specific users.

Comment: Updated the docs to state that Excel REST API is not yet generally available for personal accounts. The changelog will be updated once the support is made available. Thanks.